# UniswapV2 swapExactTokensForTokens Question

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ether, ethers.js, hardhat

I have question does UniswapV2 swapExactTokensForTokens function charge fees ? And if yes does expected amount input should be like this Expected price after fee subtraction?